# XML document being parsed as single element instead of sequence of nodes

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Given xml that looks like this:

```
<Store>
<foo>
<book>
<isbn>123456</isbn>
</book>
<title>XYZ</title>
<checkout>no</checkout>
</foo>
<bar>
<book>
<isbn>7890</isbn>
</book>
<title>XYZ2</title>
<checkout>yes</checkout>
</bar>
</Store>
```

I am getting this as my parsed xmldoc:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> xmldoc = minidom.parse('bar.xml')
>>> xmldoc.toxml()
u'<?xml version="1.0" ?><Store>\n<foo>\n<book>\n<isbn>123456</isbn>\n</book>\n<t
itle>XYZ</title>\n<checkout>no</checkout>\n</foo>\n<bar>\n<book>\n<isbn>7890</is
bn>\n</book>\n<title>XYZ2</title>\n<checkout>yes</checkout>\n</bar>\n</Store>'
```

Is there an easy way to pre-process this document so that when it is parsed, it isn't parsed as a single xml element?

Comment: If the xml seems familiar, it's because I ripped it out of another StackOverflow question.  Apologies to the original source.

Comment: not sure what you want to do - isn't the .toxml() call causing it to be output as a text file?  I would think that the output above is what you expect to get from .toxml().  how come you read an xml and then output an xml document again right away?  do you want to do sth in between?

Answer (score 2):

An XML document always has a single root element.  If you don't care about the root element, just ignore it and look at its children instead!

For example, using the more modern element-tree (but minidom offers similar possibilities in this respect):

```
try:
  import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
except ImportError:
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xmlin = '''<Store>
<foo>
<book>
<isbn>123456</isbn>
</book>
<title>XYZ</title>
<checkout>no</checkout>
</foo>
<bar>
<book>
<isbn>7890</isbn>
</book>
<title>XYZ2</title>
<checkout>yes</checkout>
</bar>
</Store>'''

root = et.fromstring(xmlin)

for child in root.getchildren():
  print et.tostring(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmldoc` is a parsed XML object.  `toxml()` asks it to convert itself back to a string of XML text again.  Explore a little further:

```
>>> xmldoc.childNodes
[<DOM Element: Store at 0x212b788>]
>>> xmldoc.childNodes[0].childNodes
[<DOM Text node "u'\n'">, <DOM Element: foo at 0x212bcd8>, <DOM Text node "u'\n'">, <DOM Element: bar at 0x212b2d8>, <DOM Text node "u'\n'">]
```

Then, realize that DOM is difficult to work with and read about [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm).